# How to enforce keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.10, gnome-shell-extension

I have set the keyboard shortcut `Super+K` to "Move to workspace above". But the "Pop shell" extension does it's thing.

I also have set the keyboard shortcut `Super+2` to "Switch to workspace 2". But when I press the keys the Dock switches to the second item in it.

Is there a way to enforce my own keyboard shortcut configuration over other extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not systematically: only in as far as you have control over what currently is using the shortcut. You have to disable the existing binding first. Most visible are the shortcut keys exposed in "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts". Many other bindings are hidden in various configuration settings, accessible in `dconf-editor`. Applications running in the background also may enable global keybindings.

For the two examples you give:

- Look to the Pop Shell extension, and see if you can disable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> there.
- Default assignment of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is to launch the second favorite in the dock. Remove that assignment by diving into `dconf-editor` or with a command, `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-2 "[]"`.

You see, this is a "case by case" approach.

Comment: Pop shell has no such configuration. Setting 'switch-to-application-2' to '[]' had no effect. Funny thing is: Setting 'switch-to-application-1' to '[]' worked fine.

Comment: I tested the command explicitly myself before posting. Not sure why it does not work for you.

Comment: Probably another extention which handles the same key. Shouldn't user defined keybindings always win over application defined ones?